# ObservableList#contains() returns false for existing item

Tags: javafx-2

I try to use the OberservableLists contains function to check if the given element is already in the List and if not add it.
My Code looks like:

```
ObservableList<Device> devicesScannerList = FXCollections.observableArrayList()
deviceScannerList.add((Device)dev);
```

Later on i do

```
Device dev = (Device)devices.get(0);
boolean deviceExists =  devicesScannerList.contains(dev);
if (deviceExists){....}
```

The problem is that deviceExists is always false but i can see in debug mode that devicesScannerList already contains the given device and i don`t want to add it again.

Do i missunderstand the contains function?
Help would be great

Thx
Ingo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `Device` class implements `equals` and `hashCode` methods correctly.

E.g. if you create 2 `Device` objects with exactly same data they will not be considered the same by `ObservableArrayList` (or any List) unless Device have `equals/hashCode` implemented.

See next example:

```
public class ObsListTest {

    static class Device {
        int value;

        public Device(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<Device> list = FXCollections.<Device>observableArrayList();
        Device data1 = new Device(1);
        Device anotherData1 = new Device(1);
        list.add(data1);
        System.out.println(list.contains(data1)); // true
        System.out.println(list.contains(anotherData1)); // false
    }
}
```

But this code will work (prints true both times) if you add next to Device:

```
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            return this.value == ((Device) obj).value;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 7 + 5*value; // 5 and 7 are random prime numbers
        }
```

See more details here: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)